# Where can I find a TeraTerm User Guide?

Tags: terminal, console, serial-port

I am using TeraTerm for terminal emulation. I'd like to create a link on my Win10 desktop, to start TT with specific connection params for a COM port.

As a reference, I have command lines that open a telnet terminal, in the form of:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe" /T=1 telnet://11.22.33.44:2301
```

But, I need serial port connection (through COM3).

Searching for the TT documentation, Google points to https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual, but this domain seem to be dead.

1. Was a manual ever published for this utility program?
2. Is there a downloadable (pdf) version of the manual?
3. What would be the command line params for the connection over COM3?

**UPDATE:** site seems to be alive but extremely slow, so need a few reload attempts but eventually get some response. Is there a faster mirror to this site?

Comment: Honestly, something is up with up with the site, give it some time... I was just in there a couple days ago and it was 100 times faster than now, I don't know why but I am guessing it's a temporary thing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a temporary site glitch. Much better now.

For reference, a sample command line to start the session in a COM mode:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\teraterm\ttermpro.exe" /C=3 /BAUD=460800 /CDATABIT=8 /CPARITY=none /CSTOPBIT=1 /CFLOWCTRL=none /CDELAYPERCHAR=0 /CDELAYPERLINE=0
```

Alternatively, an `*.ini` setup file can be used for setting all the session and window parameters. In order to set the window configuration setting, a reference setup file can be created by saving the settings of a running session, under `Setup` -> `Save setup...` menu. Then it can be used with the following command parameter:

```
... /F="path-to-ini-file"
```